# Song in Harry Potter movie (Ellington?)

Tags: soundtrack, jazz, swing

So there is a swing song in the Happy Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban movie. It just plays on the background as Harry comes to Lupins office, hardly noticeable so you cannot put it into Shazam or something. I think it's quite famous song from the 20s-30s era but however I tried I couldn't google what it is.

Here is a youtube clip of that scene:

Does anyone know what song that is?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Harry Potter Wiki][1] on fandom.com:

> The second song played on the gramophone in Lupin's office when he tells Harry Potter that he has been sacked from his professor post is "Jungle Jazz Room" composed by Steve Grey.

That credit is also given in the information section of the below YouTube video of the "Lupin's Resignation" scene:

The song, composed in 1995 as stock music, is meant to evoke

> up-tempo New York Cotton Club, bright jungle rhythms. Early 30s (1930-1933)

The track (a "commercial cut") can be heard at https://www.apmmusic.com/albums/BR-0191. The above quote is also from that site.

Answer (score 0):

It's Hot Liquorice by Dick Walter, a BBC composer/arranger.  You'll see many wrong answers, but that is the correct one.
You can listen to it on YouTube and you'll notice it is the same exact song, not just one that has similar rhythms.